# query consult JSON fields in ruby on rails

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

how to make a query in a field of JSON type to return only one key? For example I have this model `ActivityPart` below and I want to return the `activity_json` field just a key named `"image"`.

```
ActivityPart < ApplicationRecord {
                   :id => :integer,
        :activity_type => :string,
        :activity_json => :json,
           :created_at => :datetime,
           :updated_at => :datetime,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code:

```rb
activity_parties = ActivityPart.select("activity_json->'image' AS image")
```

And you will be able to access this column for each record

```rb
activity_parties.each { |party| party.image }
```